# Is there a scala IDE that works hand in hand with the compiler?

Tags: ide, scala

First to code in scala I used Intellij, but my computer couldn't handle both Intellij and SBT at the same time so I switched to Sublime.

I think one of the factor of overhead in Intellij with Scala plugin is that both Intellij and SBT are doing type inferring and type checking which are pretty hard tasks in scala.

In my mind it should be possible to use the types computed at the last compilation by scalac, to provide auto-completion and minimal type checking.

Also the type that are successfully inferred by the IDE could be used to give a "warm-start" to the compiler.

Is there any IDE that works like that ? or any project to create one ?

Comment: What are your objections to Eclipse with the Scala plugins?

Comment: I didn't try Eclipse, but I think that in regards to their relation to scala they work pretty much the same way.